# Print and assign array values to another variable in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I face some problem while trying to print array values as shown below:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set args=
set /A argc=0
SET /A argn=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
SET args[!argn!]=%%a
SET /A argn+=1
)

FOR %%q in (%*) DO (
echo !args[%argc%]! //not able to print the value
call echo  %%args[!argc!]%%  // this worked

if "%%q" == "--snap" (
      set /A argc+=1
      set SNAP=!args[%argc%]! //this didn't work
)
if "%%q" == "--source" (
      set /A argc+=1
      call SET "SOURCE=%%args[!argc!]%%" //this didn't work too          
)
set /A argc+=1
)
```

Using this segment of code prints only the first value of the array but the other  method of using for /l works fine. 
How do i correct this?
Is it possible to store this array value in any other variable? If so, how?

Comment: `for %%q in (%*) do ...` how many parameters does your batch file get from command line?. BTW `set /a argc+=1` is preferred syntax

Comment: 13 arguments from command line. @elzooilogico

Comment: and how is the array populated? I don't see how it`s filled?

Comment: you must use either `call echo %%args[!argc!]%%` or `for %%a in (!argc!) do echo !args[%%a]!`

Comment: Array is populated as:  set /a argn=0 for %%a in (/*) do ( set args[!argn!]=%%a set argn=!argn!+1 )

Comment: Thanks. Using call echo %%args[!argc!]%% worked. But how can i now assign this value to any other variable. And how will the second method using (!argc!) work? Do yu mean argc as the total count of array values? @elzooilogico

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128617/discussion-between-rrr-and-elzooilogico).

Comment: @RRR, ALWAYS update your code with relevant code within your QUESTION.  Not in a comment.  Because you are only showing us a portion of your code we cannot assume anything. You have to show us all the code that affects how this portion of your code works.

Comment: All array management details are fully explained at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)...

Comment: @Squashman i have edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to echo a variable you haven't set, it will therefore be blank.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
Set argc=0
For %%q In (%*) Do (
    Set "args[!argc!]=%%q"
    Rem The next line is for information only   
    Call Echo=%%args[!argc!]%%
    Set/A argc+=1
)
Rem take a look at the variables
Set args[
Timeout -1
```

Comment: But how do i assign this value to another variable? @Compo

Comment: I'm not sure which value or what variable you are referring to. _the second parameter can already be referenced using **%2** or **%args[1]%** so I don't really understand why you would want to set this again as another variable_. Unless I know more I cannot really advise.

Comment: how do i set %%args[!argc!]%% to some other variable? Like, set snap=%%args[!args!]%%. Will this work?

Comment: Which arg are you wanting to set snap to equal? If you are wanting to set snap to equal all of them then just do that at the top of your script, `Set "snap=%*"`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `delayedexpansion` has been invoked and `argn` has been set to #args+1 as reported in comments,

```
set /a argn-=1
for /L %%q in (0,1,%argn%) do echo !args[%%q]!
set /a argn+=1
```

would be my preference.